# How to optimize a function being called inside a loop with variable parameters

Tags: python, flask, optimization, sqlalchemy

I have a flask app using app factory and sqlalchemy and have a class that updates all locations in a database. The structure is as follows:

clouds.py

```py
def update_location_data(location_id, data):
    # Goes through MySQL database and updates data where not equal
    location = session.get(Location, location_id)
    ...
    for index in (0, x)
        location.data[index] = new_data
    flag_modified(location, "data")
    session.add(location)
    session.commit()

def update_all_location_data(user_id):
    # Gets all locations from tracked table using user id
    # This returns a list of locations say locations
    for location in locations:
        lat = location.lat
        long = location.long
        params = {"lat": lat, "lon": long, ...}
        data = requests.get(URL, params=params).json()
        update_location_data(location.location_id, data)
```

This takes around 3.5 seconds to run for only 4 items in the location table. I'm worried this will significantly grow as the location table grows.

How would I go about optimizing this function call in the loop or optimize the whole thing so that it updates the table concurrently?

Comment: "_Goes through database and updates data where not equal_" Is this being done with a query or in python? Also what kind of database is this?

Comment: @smac89 I updated the original post with the requested details. I'm using SQLAlchemy Session object to get the row and modify details and commit that.

Comment: Well, yes, if you have to do a web request for every row, that's going to take a very long time.  You need to figure out a way to cache that data, so you only fetch it once.

Comment: @TimRoberts The problem is the data updates every hour or so. It gets new data from the API and updates the database where needed which is why I can't cache that data. Any way to run the update concurrently for the given location list?

Comment: So, you start up a background process that updates your database once an hour, and have your Flask app pull from the database,

Comment: Oh didn't even think of that. That will work, thank you sir!